# Android if a view is on top of another in FrameLayout, and is invisible, does it intercept click/touch events?

Tags: android

Android if a view is on top of another in FrameLayout, and is invisible, does it intercept click/touch events?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        // Some views here
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        //Some Views here
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what does your trials say?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because its a complicated project and will take a lot of time to build the layout and test it, this is a simplified version of the problem

Comment: there is no difference how complex the layout is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,it will intercept click events unless it's visibility is set to `GONE`.

If the above `View` is `INVISIBLE` and having the click/touch events then the below `View`'s click/touch events will be intercept.